# What is the differences between Eclipse for Java (EE) Developers and Eclipse for Mobile Developers and Eclipse Classic?

Tags: android

what is the best ide from the above ides for Android development and is there any other IDE overwhelm them?

Comment: For android dev, you only need the regular Java Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the bundled plugins. If you are not going to do any Java EE stuff (servlets, JSP, etc.). get the classic one. You can always install more plugins later if you need to. The only other (major) IDE that has good Android support is IntelliJ. Not sure where NetBeans (what is it called now?) stands, but that's Oracle technology...

Comment: My account is locked and I don't know how to unlock it , please help me ! I can't post new Questions

Comment: Not sure why you think it's locked, and why you think I can help? If you can post comments, it is most probably OK.

Comment: hello there , I cannot ask new question , what is the problem that I make ?